# Error consulta mysql, php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una consulta en MySql en un script en php:

```sql
SELECT distinct sistema, clv_nodo,
CONCAT (anio_ini,'/',mes_ini,'/',dia_ini) as fecha_ini,
CONCAT(anio_fin,'/',mes_fin,'/',dia_fin) as fecha_fin
FROM nodosp, 2016_2022
where LEFT(clv_nodo,2) = '01' order by clv_nodo, fecha_ini;
```

Dentro de MySql en phpmyadmin y MySql workbench ejecuta correctamente la consulta y me trae los datos como los requiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El problema es cuando ejecuto el script de php me manda error en el query en la parte de el WHERE, el error que me manda es:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '01' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\base\anual\pml_01_mda.php on line 18

Y no ejecuta la consulta

Comment: Pues deberias mostrarnos como construyes la consulta dentro del PHP para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Cambie la sintaxis del Query
PHP no interpreta correctamente el LEFT al iniciar con un caracter por lo que se le tienen que poner las diagonales para que indique que excluya la '

```
'SELECT distinct sistema, clv_nodo, CONCAT (anio_ini,\'/\',mes_ini,\'/\',dia_ini) as fecha_ini, CONCAT(anio_fin,\'/\',mes_fin,\'/\',dia_fin) as fecha_fin FROM nodosp, 2016_2022 where LEFT(clv_nodo,2) = \'02\' order by clv_nodo, fecha_ini;'
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).